# Field ‘browser’ doesn’t contain a valid alias configuration-angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I have just started with angular 2 and getting following weird error. I don't think something is wrong with the code and it's something to do with the configuration. I have followed this tutorial.
http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2017/06/angular-2-nested-components.html.
I have updated my angular-cli version as well but still getting same error.

```
 ERROR in ./src/app/employee/employee.component.ts
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/employee/employee.component.html' in 'C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\src\app\employee'
resolve './app/employee/employee.component.html' in 'C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\src\app\employee'
 using description file: C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/employee)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/employee)
using description file: C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/employee/app/employee/employee.component.html)
  no extension
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\src\app\employee\app\employee\employee.component.html doesn't exist
  .ts
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    C:\Users\a\angular-tour-of-employees\src\app\employee\app\employee\employee.component.html.ts doesn't exist
  .js
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

My Angular configuration

```
@angular/cli: 1.6.8
 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
 @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
 @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
 @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
 @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
 @schematics/angular: 0.1.17
 typescript: 2.5.3
 webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: Don't use old tutorials like that. Angular has changed a lot in the last year. Just dive into [angular.io](https://angular.io) and check the documentation, examples and other resources

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks . i will do that. but still do you have solution for this problem.

Comment: maybe if you can add your  `employee.component.ts ` component definition, and your folder structure